# How would I programmatically determine all the currently existing dirs in a Github dir page?

Tags: php, github, web-scraping

I have this: https://github.com/bitcoin-core/guix.sigs/tree/main/22.0

In PHP, I'm trying to grab a list of all subdirs in that dir, as it exists at that given moment. For all I know, they sometimes remove and add (or even rename) the existing ones. In other words: `[ '0xb10c', 'CoinForensics', 'Emzy', ... ];`

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Do I really have to cURL-fetch the webpage (Github/Microsoft loves blocking my bots) and then try to parse them out from the absolute clusterduck of HTML code?

Do they really not provide this list of "independent verifiers" as some sort of computer-parseable list somewhere?

My ultimate goal is to be able to fetch all of their verifications for the current version of Bitcoin Core, such as: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitcoin-core/guix.sigs/main/22.0/fanquake/all.SHA256SUMS`, and compare it with the "official" one on BitcoinCore.org, and it they all don't match, I will not install the new update. To be able to do this, I need to know the list of "users" to construct the URLs to fetch.

I don't understand why they always seem to actively make one step impossible or near-impossible to automate, even in highly technical and security-related contexts where it makes no sense. I really hope that I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Could you not just compare hashes between https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitcoin-core/guix.sigs/main/22.0/fanquake/all.SHA256SUMS and https://bitcoincore.org/bin/bitcoin-core-22.0/SHA256SUMS?

Comment: Why are you trying to scrape the web interface instead of just using git to check out the repo?

Comment: @waterloomatt Huh?

Comment: @Sammitch "using git"?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is probably to sparsely clone the remote repository locally, then scan the local filesystem for directory changes.

Do the following once to set up a sparse clone:

```
git init guix.sigs
cd guix.sigs
git remote add -f origin https://github.com/bitcoin-core/guix.sigs
git config core.sparseCheckout true
echo "22.0/" >>.git/info/sparse-checkout
```

Now do the following at the start of each 'run' where you want to see what directories have updated:

```
git pull origin main
```

You can then look in `guix.sigs/22.0` for any changes.

Comment: So I need to install software: `git`?

Comment: Yes - github is a git repository, that just happens to have a web frontend for convenience. If you want to do anything programmatic with the files/code on a github repository, you don't do it via the web interface.